# \0 values in Python dataframes

Tags: python, string, dataframe, null, utf

I have a dataframe column called `amount` in python containing `null` and `"\0"` values. I want to convert this null and `\0` values into `\u0000`
string function replace worked for null values. but for \0 values its not working. here is the example of my data.

```
amount
null
"\0"
"\0"
"\0"
"\0"
"\0"
```

I check the datatype using df['amount'].dtypes and it is string. why i cant replace the value?
I had try using str.replace("\0", "\u0000") but its not working.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What return `df['amount'].head().tolist()` ?

Comment: @jezrael they return 

Out[326]:
['\\0', '\\0', '\\0', '\\0', '\\0']

Comment: @Ducker - How working `str.replace("\\0", "\u0000")` ?

Comment: @jezrael it produce result like this     '\0'

Comment: @Ducker - for me working  `df['amount'].str.replace(r"\\0", r"\\0000")` in `python 3`

Answer (score 0):

For me working:

```
df['amount'].str.replace(r"\\0", r"\\0000")
```